# How to reload/re-initialize Kafka Consumer with new topic list added to DB

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have this code that loads when my node back end starts, I just changed this code from using a static list of topics for the Kafka Consumer and it now uses an array of topics it reads from the database.  What I do not know is how to initialize the Kafka Consumer to reload the list of topics from the database when a user adds one using a react front end.  I can make an API call from front end to back end but once I get to back end I don't know what to call for the Kafka Consumer to re-read the list from the DB and start to consume that list of topics that may have changed by user adding or removing.

This code uses the node-rdkafka package.  I did see a consumer.disconnect function but wasn't sure if that was the best approach here or if I can just reload my init function??

```
async init(success, error, services) {

    const client = new pg.Client(config.connectionString);
    var topicsList;

    await consumer.connect(); 
    await client.connect()
    await client.query('SELECT topic FROM public.job;').then(topics => {
        topicsList = Array.from(Object.keys(topics.rows), k=>topics.rows[k].topic)
    });
    await client.end(); 

   consumer.on('ready', function() {
      //consumer.subscribe(['some_Data', 'other_Data', 'and_more_Data', 'deez_Data', 'etc_Data', 'hooha_Data', 'mine_Data']);
      consumer.subscribe(topicsList);
      consumer.consume();
    })
    consumer.on('data', function(data) {
        const { container } = services;

        success(data, services, 7)  //write data to DB

    });

  }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you looked at Kafka Connect JDBC or Debezium Postgres connector?

Comment: Connecting to the database is not my problem, more of how to get Kafka to re-load the list of topics on an event

Comment: Where are you handling backend POST calls? You need to close the current consumer, then recreate and connect the entire consumer object if you add any topics to your database.